# Set the color of each arrow and dot in a biplot(prcomp)

Tags: r, colors, plot, pca

I need a more complex color labels for my pca `biplot`.
Using `USArrests` data example: I want that for each variable (Murder, etc) it plots a pre-defined colored arrow, and for each observation (Alabama, etc) it plots a pre-defined colored name.

At this time, it seems to me that `ggbiplot`, which probably could resolve that, needs dev version of R installed.

I would like to try `biplot(prcomp(), scale=T, center=T)`, instead of `vegan` functions.

I'm trying to figure out a way to configure `biplot(prcomp())` arrows color by handling `USArrests.pca$rotation[i:f,]` and observations names color manipulating `USArrests.pca$x[b:e,]`, but i am not being well succeded.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you post the code you used, you might increase your odds of getting a response. At the moment your data-objects are not available for inspection or testing.